# Deploying MVC 4 Application under IIS8 : HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I'am running windows server 2012 with IIS8.

I just try to add a newly created MVC4 application with visual studio 2012 as a virtual directory in IIS 8 and then convert it into an application.
First I get this error :

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module          IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler         Not yet determined
Error Code      0x80070005
Config Error    Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File     \\?\C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\web.config
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/mvc
Physical Path   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User      Not yet determined
```

I searched for the solution and I founded that I have to grant Read permission on the application folder for IIS_IUSRS

I did it ! then I have this error now  :

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Detailed Error Information:
Module              IIS Web Core
Notification        MapRequestHandler
Handler             StaticFile
Error Code          0x80070002
Requested URL       http://localhost:80/mvc/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fmvc
Physical Path       C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Account\Login
Logon Method        Anonymous
Logon User          Anonymous
```

What's wrong ??

Thank you !